# Git differences between OSX and Linux

Tags: ubuntu, osx-lion, git, version-control

This has been driving me somewhat insane but I can't find any information on it.  I have both Mac and a Linux (Ubuntu) machines.  I work on both but I'm finding Git is behaving very differently during merges and rebases.  I've just done *exactly* the same rebase on both machines (purely for the purpose of establishing if they really are behaving differently).  On Ubuntu it went very smoothly.  I had to fix conflicts and `git rebase --continue` 3 times and when the rebase was complete, everything was as I expected it to be.

On OSX however, I had to resolve dozens of conflicts, use `--continue` and `--skip` and at the end, I did not have the expected code.  Right off the bat, OSX was identifying different conflicts so even before I had the chance to resolve conflicts differently, the behaviour between the platforms had diverged.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues?  I'd really love to work out what is going on as I currently have no confidence in being able to rebase or merge correctly on OSX...

Git versions:
OSX - 1.7.4.4
Ubuntu - 1.7.9.5

Comment: @slhck added that info

Comment: You can easily update Git on OS X through the [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) or [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/). Git's now at 1.7.10, so there might have been some fixes in between. Not a Git expert though.

Comment: @slhck While it's possible and I'll update anyway, I don't think this is a version problem...  If I find it is, I'll post an update.

Comment: Have you compared your `~/.gitconfig` across the machines?

Comment: @KevinReid it's the same. Only defines editor, excludes_file, name and email